# Error importing X509Certificate2 certificate from keyvault in powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to import a certificate from azure key vault into a X509Certificate2 in powershell, and I'm coming across several blockers.  So i start out with:

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<vaultName>" -Name "<certName>"
$ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue)
try {
     $secretValueText = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)
} finally {
     [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)
}
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secretValueText)
```

and I get an error on the last line that the 'input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character'

looking at the text inside $secretValueText, i see data formatted like:

```
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----  
WWWWWW...
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
XXXXXX....
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
YYYYY.....
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
ZZZZZZZ.....
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How can i convert that text so that i can then run

```
$authcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$authcert.Import($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

I've also tried:

```
$secretPlain = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secret.SecretValue
```

and that actually allows the conversion to work, but on the '$authcert.import' i get the error  "Exception calling import, cannot find the requested object"

Comment: A key and a base64 string look the same.  The both consist of printable ASCII characters.  So I believe you do not need to use the method FromBase64String.  The $secretValueText is your key.

Comment: if i just run $authcert.import on $secretValueText, then i get an error 'Ilegal characters in path'

Comment: Best way of handling the certificate is with OpenSSl (see https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OpenSSL/1.0.0) and see how to use OpenSSL with https://www.tencentcloud.com/document/product/214/6155

Comment: it's not a package i can use.  i need to use the X509Certificates object in order to work with another dependency

Comment: You are using Powershell.  What is wrong with creating a pem file and then reading the pem file?

Comment: the end result i need is to populate the X509Certificates  object.  i then pass that object to another 3rd party tool.  i don't have much flexibility in the final result/object that i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `-AsPlainText` parameter when executing the command `ConvertFrom-SecureString`:

```bash
$secretValueText = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secret.SecretValue -AsPlainText
```

Full sample:

```bash
$keyVaultName = "<vaultName>"
$certName = "<certName>"

$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $certName
$secretValueText = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secret.SecretValue -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secretValueText)

$authcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 `
  ($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

You can also retrieve the secret value using the `-AsPlainText` parameter when executing the command `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`:

```bash
$keyVaultName = "<vaultName>"
$certName = "<certName>"

$secretValueText = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $certName -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($secretValueText)

$authcert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 `
  ($secretByte, "", "Exportable,PersistKeySet")
```

Comment: for your first option, I get an error on the 'ConvertFrom-SecureString' that 'a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsPlainText''
For your second option, i get the same error on [Convert]::FromBase64String that 'the input is not a valid base-64 string as it contains a non base 64 character, more than two padding characers, or an illegal character among the padding characters'

Comment: Which version of powershell and az powershell are you running ?

Comment: using PS version 5.1 and az client 2.49

Comment: if i use PS 7 then the 'ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText' works for me, but i get the same error on the FromBase64String conversion

Comment: if you download the cert from kv, does it look ok ?

Comment: it does to me, but then i might not know what 'ok' looks like properly.  You can see in my comment above that i give an example of what $secretValueText looks like, and i thought that should be good.
if i get rid of all the ---- BEGIN --- lines, and take 1 certificate, and get rid of the \n in the file, then i can import one of the certs as the object, but it doesn't help me because it says it's missing the private key.  So it looks like the file is good, but formatted wrong?

Comment: Can you create a new cert in KV? auto generated and selft signed and see if that work for you ?

Comment: ok, yeah that worked.  there must be something funky with the other cert, wish i knew what.  thank you though!